# Pass data back to parent using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

im using window.open to log in using google below are my codes.

```
$('window').ready(function() {
    $('#googlebtn').click(function() {
        mywindow = window.open("'<?php echo base_url();?>'+authenticate/google","Auth","height=470,width=430")

        window.setInterval(function(){            
            if(mywindow.closed == true){
                window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>'+'checklogin/email';                
            }
        },3000);
    });   
});
```

but what i want is to verify the data from the new window opened after close.
i already tried declaring variable to the parent then in my new window

```
window.opener.varFromParent = '1';
window.close();
```

then try to verify my variable to my parent inside the timer

```
if(varFromParent == '1'){alert(1);}
```

i cant get it working.

Comment: any error message in the console?

Comment: @Katrin console of my parent? because as soon as the user authenticated using google.i will use window.close()

Comment: so what is your outcome now? no alert box showing the varFromParent value changed?

Comment: by the way, you are not referencing the variable mywindow,
var mywindow = window.open("'<?php echo base_url();?>'+authenticate/google","Auth","height=470,width=430")

Comment: @Katrin sorry for that. i just mistype the code. yeah my variable didnt change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a form with hidden field.

```
parent.html
<form name="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="hdn" />
</form>

child.html
<script>
window.opener.document.myForm.hdn.value="Any value";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
window.parent.varFromParent = '1';
```

instead of opener.

window.parent just returns the window object of your parent window.